# Cannot use port 80 twice with different ip addresses?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, port, ip-address, port-80

I have an interesting problem right now. On a Windows Server 2012 R2 I have two IP addresses, say `192.0.2.1` and `192.0.2.2`. On one address e.g. `192.0.2.1` a web server runs on port `80`, which is implemented in C# using `HttpListener`. At the other address e.g. `192.0.2.2` I try to open port `80` using a Go program and `http.server{}`. The Go program receives an error message that the port cannot be opened. The C# program is started first. I start the Go program with administrator permissions.

When I use `netstat` to check which ports are in use on which addresses, the second address `192.0.2.2` is completely unused. Port `80` is only opened by the C# program at the first address i.e. `192.0.2.1`.

**It makes no sense at all. Am I missing something?**

I had a similar scenario two weeks ago with Ubuntu and two Go programs, both using port `443` on different IP addresses. That was no problem at all and ran immediately.

Comment: You need to show some code. One of your two programs has a bug. And this probably should be on [so].

Comment: Output of netstat would also help.

Answer (score 1):

The web server needs to be configured to bind to the intended IP address only. If its configured to bind to any address you can't use the same port with any other address.

Plain `netstat` only displays *connected* sockets. You need to use `-a` to display the listening, possibly unconnected ports. Any port that is allocated for listening cannot be used in another way. Using `-ao` is also handy as it'll display the PID alongside the port.